# How do I solve kernel error in the console in spyder 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, anaconda, spyder

I recently tried to run my code in Spyder 3.7 and my Ipython console showed the following error, this is the case for all my codes:

```
An error ocurred while starting the kernel

The error is:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\20191881\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\plugins\ipythonconsole.py", line 1572, in create_kernel_manager_and_kernel_client
kernel_manager.start_kernel(stderr=stderr_handle)
File "C:\Users\20191881\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 240, in start_kernel
self.write_connection_file()
File "C:\Users\20191881\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 547, in write_connection_file
kernel_name=self.kernel_name
File "C:\Users\20191881\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 212, in write_connection_file
with secure_write(fname) as f:
File "C:\Users\20191881\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 112, in __enter__
return next(self.gen)
File "C:\Users\20191881\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 102, in secure_write
with os.fdopen(os.open(fname, open_flag, 0o600), mode) as f:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\20191881\\AppData\\Roaming\\jupyter\\runtime\\kernel�caf3ec3.json'
```

I am very new to spyder and I have absolutely no idea how to solve this.
I have already tried to uninstall anaconda and install it again but the same error keeps appearing...
Does anyone have any idea how I could solve this?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please close Spyder, open the Anaconda Prompt and run there `conda update --all`. That should fix your problem.

Comment: THANK YOU! This solved the problem!